# Wordpress multisite dashboard link not working

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I moved my site to Azure. Before moving to Azure, I used Wordpress multisite and everything is good. After moving to Azure, the multisite dashboard link is not working, but multisite still working - just the multisite dashboard link is not working. I can't access it to manage multisite,wp-admin/network not working, it shows "**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**", I checked phpmyadmin db's site url, it seems ok, how do I fix this problem?

multisite wp-config.php setting as below:

```
/* MU setting */<br>
define('MULTISITE', true);<br>
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);<br>
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.bunsbao.com' );<br>
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');<br>
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);<br>
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);<br>
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');<br>
define('COOKIEPATH', '');<br>
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');<br>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hello there.How did it go for you?  Currently having some sort of this issue: on my multisite dashboard, the Sites option is gone!. This happened I think after changing my admin password directly on  database via phpMyAdmin; got to log in but no multisite functionality! Tried removing all cookies manually as well via config.php as suggested here: https://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/   .  Any hint on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are facing a WordPress Multisite Redirect Loop issue, it could be a cookie configuration issue in WP, and you can refer to [Resolving The WordPress Multisite Redirect Loop](https://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/) for the explanation and solution.

And also, you can try to follow [Convert WordPress to Multisite in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-convert-wordpress-multisite) to reinstall the WordPress Multisite.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.